# Getting Drawable with Picasso

Tags: java, android, kotlin, drawable, picasso

Recently I got acquainted with the Picasso framework for downloading pictures from the Internet. But, the matter is that, as I understood, the framework itself can not give exactly what I want. I have some data class which uses for recycler view's list. And there must be Drawable, because I'm using something like that:

```
holder?.photoView?.setImageResource(userList[position].photoId)
```

in my custom adapter onBindViewHolder. So, I already have an property that must be used. Well, not to be confused, just say that I need to get Drawable resource from this:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).centerCrop().fit()
```

or something like that.
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

First of all, my fragment:

```
fun setImg(url: String) {//Code that doesn't work
    val url = userList[position].photoId
    Picasso.with(context).load(url).placeHolder(R.drawable.image).into(imageView)
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hotels, container, false)

    val rv = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.hotelsView)
    rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
    val list = ArrayList<Hotel>()
    list.add(Item("Milk (Just for example)", "$1.99", setImg("img")))
    list.add(Hotel("Banana", "$2.99", setImg("img")))

    var adapter = CustomAdapter(list)
    rv.adapter = adapter

    return view
}
```

Custom Adapter:

```
class CustomAdapter(val userList: ArrayList<Hotel>): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
    holder?.textTitle?.text = userList[position].title
    holder?.textPrice?.text = userList[position].price
    //holder?.photoView?.setImageResource(userList[position].photoId)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.view_adapter, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return userList.size
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val textTitle = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_first)
    val textPrice = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_second)
    val photoView = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.photoView)
}
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:ignore="NamespaceTypo">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFF">
    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photoView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:id="@+id/text_first"
            android:text="Title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:text="Price"
            android:id="@+id/text_second"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

That's all.

Comment: you need an ImageView. Not a drawable. Picasso uses URLs to go INTO an ImageView.

Comment: @DroiDev but what to do if my case require drawable?...

Comment: you can use a placeholder... see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ImageView imageView = findViewByID(R.id.imageview);
String url = "http://www.website.com/image.png";
Picasso.with(context).load(url).placeHolder(R.drawable.image).into(imageView);
```

XML in your Layout Resource

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This will take the URL from the internet and place it into the ImageView.

It looks like you are in a adapter... So you can do something like this...

```
ImageView imageView = findViewByID(R.id.imageview);
String url = userList[position].photoId;
Picasso.with(context).load(url).placeHolder(R.drawable.image).into(imageView);
```

Side note: You don't NEED a placeholder. When your images are loading, the space where the imageview is will be white until the image loads.

---

Looking more at your code... this is wrong..

```
list.add(Item("Milk (Just for example)", "$1.99", setImg("img")))
list.add(Hotel("Banana", "$2.99", setImg("img")))
```

Should be something like this.

```
list.add(Item("Milk (Just for example)", "$1.99", "http://www.google.com/image.jpg"))
list.add(Hotel("Banana", "$2.99", "http://www.google.com/image.jpg"))
```

And then in your adapter do this.... (its in java.... does picasso support kotlin?)

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
    holder?.textTitle?.text = userList[position].title
    holder?.textPrice?.text = userList[position].price
    String url = userList[position].url
    Picasso.with(context).load(url).placeHolder(R.drawable.image).into(photoView);
    //holder?.photoView?.setImageResource(userList[position].photoId)
}
```

Comment: This means, I need to create empty drawable and set it as background for Image View and only then use this code? I'm sorry, I'm just don't understand how it works (Because I found some private method, called getPlaceholderDrawable() and it confuse me..)

Comment: dont over think it. your XML can look like the following (edit coming soon)

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your edit. Yes, I'm using Adapter for Card View, which is used in Recycler View. And, I'm afraid, if all items from list will be with one image on it. May be I should edit my post and follow all code, I'm using. Within reasonable limits, of course

Comment: it wont be the same image. im working on a roject righ tnow. as long as you get the item in the list at position, youll be fine. promise. :)

Comment: Hm, no, I think I should edit my question to give you my code. This code, unfortunately, does not fit in my case, because I have everything in different classes.

Comment: do you have a model and setters/getters? for me, i am feeded a model, adding it to a list, that list controls my listview, and then in my adpater, i get the list.get(position).getImageURL(); which returns a string value that was set.

Comment: Not at all. In Kotlin, I don't need getter any getters and setters. The're looking like this one:

Comment: the list.add(Item("Milk (Just for example)", "$1.99", setImg("img"))).... the "img" needs to be a URL. "http://www.website.com/image.jpg" for example.

Comment: Oh my god, it helps! Thank you so much! But there is something comfuse "its in java.... does picasso support kotlin?"... Of course yes. Kotlin is fully compatible with java. So, no matter what is the framework lang, it will be compatible. Okey, then. As I understand, you are well versed in Picasso. Can you find out, please, how to make the picture take up the whole width of CardView? That's how it's done now: https://i.imgur.com/MfTgdkJ.png

Comment: The ImageView in your XML, set it to match_parent for the width. Then, also add scaleType: CENTER_CROP to it